# Building myself OpenCV with CUDA. Error LNK1104

Tags: c++, opencv

I need OpenCV 3.2.0 with CUDA8.0.
I'm following [this](http://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-opencv-v3-2-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/) tutorial and at the last step - building the INSTALL project - Visual Studio 2013 giving me about 45 errors like:

`LNK1104: cannot open file "..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_world320d.lib`

The error occurs about 30-40 minutes after start building.

This is the first error that occurs:

```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\combaseapi.h(229): error : identifier "IUnknown" is undefined
9>  
9>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\combaseapi.h(229): warning : expression has no effect
9>  
9>D:\OCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/base.hpp(365): warning : function declared with "noreturn" does return
9>  
9>  1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/tomus/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_000018ac_00000000-6_gftt.cpp4.ii".
9>CUSTOMBUILD : nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
9>  gftt.cu
9>  CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gftt.cu.obj.cmake:264 (message):
9>    Error generating file
9>    D:/OCV/build2/modules/world/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/cudaimgproc/src/cuda/Debug/cuda_compile_generated_gftt.cu.obj
```

After that I have 47 errors LNK1104.

Comment: can you try to compile without Cuda? It should be much faster and if the error occurs there, too, testing/fixing will be much easier (and you can turn on compiling with cuda later)!

Comment: can you find the very first error messages (there are multiple projects compiled and maybe those are just the errors of the last project)? Maybe there are previous errors and the .lib files juts couldn't be built. Then you'll have to fix the first errors!

Comment: I unchecked WITH_CUDA in CMake and build the INSTALL project. There are no errors and 58 project succeeded.

Comment: I have a lot of warnings like: "function declared with "noreturn" does return" or "field of class type without a DLL interface used in a class with a DLL interface", I am waiting for the first error.

Comment: Build output:
[link](https://pastebin.com/ndpQdaj1)
[link](https://pastebin.com/1UZCF6w3)

Comment: have a look at: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6676
and https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6500 maybe it is already is the newest openCV source code (try to get the newest daily code from git or sth.) or you might have to use one of the workarounds, if it's the same problem.